# Unable to log into website using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to use Python requests and BeautifulSoup to try and write a web scraper. I've tried to log into this website using several solutions online, however wasn't able to do so.

One reason for this is that the form elements do not use conventional scheme. A snippet of the website code has been posted below. Any help would be appreciated.

[This image contains the code of the form element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG1d8.png)

Edit 1: I am fairly new to this and therefore have been stuck at quite an elemental step. I tried to change the key values of my login credentials and it doesn't seem to help.

[My code as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41jh2.png)

Comment: Maybe show what you have tried? Maybe not with a screenshot of the code?

Comment: login and CATCH the COOKIE generated and USE IT for another call to the site

Comment: There are hidden fields in that form, e.g. `authenticity_token` which you probably also need to send

Comment: Please post code as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score -1):

you can have some reason why it's can work. Your code will would be appreciated too. The first reason why its' can't work who comes to my mind, it's because you need emulate a real browser, like Google Chrome or Firefox.

In fact, you need to have a user agent. By default python user agent request is not like a [true user agent](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Chrome).

After you need to catch cookie of the weeb site and user it for the login.

You have many solution to do that, i can explain two when i have use:
 - [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) generate a the behavior of a browser.
 - Use request but use all options like a browser : generate a user agent and also use cookie (the server need to think you are a true user).

Comment: Could you point me towards relevant links to learn to do what you just mentioned?

Comment: You have 2 links in the previews post (click on : "True user agent" for example of user agent, or click on "Selenium" for the doc of this libary). If you want an full explication about [request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) (click on request for the link) and with a better english than my :D

Answer (score -1):

Dayle, you must post your approach to the question.

I made crawler by this way,

```
response = urlopen(page_url)
    if 'text/html' in response.getheader('Content-Type'):
        print("hello 123")
        html_bytes = response.read()
        html_string = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
```

and passed this html_string to BeautifulSoup.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')
html_string = soup.prettify()
```

I think this makes it much simpler.